# LiveCode: Accessing Windows System Menu

Tags: windows, livecode

Is it possible to access the [Windows System Menu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_menus_in_Microsoft_Windows#System_menu) natively in LiveCode in order to add items to the menu? If not, can this be done using an external?

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NfaE.png) of the menu.

Comment: If you mean the start menu, you can do that with Installer Maker, a LiveCode plugin created by my company Economy-x-Talk. Installer Maker is available as a plug-in for the commercial edition of LC and as a standalone application for people who don't have (the commercial edition of) LiveCode. Other software packages may be able to do the same.

Comment: @Mark thanks for looking into this. I'm referring to the actual [Windows System Menu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_menus_in_Microsoft_Windows#System_menu) that pops up when the user left-clicks the application icon in the upper-left corner of standard window canvas or right-clicks the Title Bar.

Comment: I get it. I can make an external for it, but I don't do those things for free. If you want to try it yourself, perhaps there is some code here on SO for it. All you'd have to do is embed it in an external.

Answer (score 0):

LiveCode can't access the System Menu. You would need an external for it. According to the [Wikipedia page you linked to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_menus_in_Microsoft_Windows#System_menu), you can do this with the `GetSystemMenu` function.